# value list with index to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'd like to write a function that converts the index and the value of the list to the dictionary, for example: (below code is in python).

```
(a, b, c, d) = range(4)
l = [5, 6, 7, 8]
dic = {}
def fun(index_list, l):
    # do something
dic = fun ([a, b, d], l)

>>> print dic
>>> {'0':5, '1':6, '3':8}
```

or

```
`>>> {'a':5, 'b':6, 'c':8}`
```

Any idea?

The second result is it possible?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Your second example is not possible, since variable names are not known from values (and aren't knowable, especially since any number of variables with different names can refer to the same value). If you had a list of strings instead of a list of numbers you could achieve it.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `{'a':5, 'b':6, 'c':8}`, since you shouldn't be tying variable names to their values in any way that's necessary to the logic of the code. There are incredibly ugly and fragile hacks that might get you there, but let's leave those tools in the shed.

To get values to values, it's easy to `zip` and `dict`.

```
a, b, c, d = range(4)
lst = [5, 6, 7, 8]
dic = dict(zip((a, b, d), lst))
# dic == {0: 5, 1: 6, 3: 7}
```

Although now I'm seeing you expected `3` to map to `8`. You can do that, but it's an extra step.

```
master_dic = dict(zip((a, b, c, d), lst))
dic = {k:master_dic[k] for k in ('a', 'b', 'd')}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is simple, but just use a dict comprehension:

```
dic = {str(v): l[v] for v in (a, b, d)}
```